# Watermark background images in div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create a watermark from stored images.

But the watermark effect the upper layers, and scaledown the color of all div..

```
<div style="background:url({{blogthreadlist.blogUri}}) no-repeat;background-position:center;opacity:0.6;filter:alpha(opacity=60);z-index: -1">
    <div class="col-md-12">Something else</div>
    <div class="col-md-12">Something more..</div>
    <div class="col-md-12">Something at the end</div>
</div>
```

Im using bootstrap and Angular..

How do I create at watermark on in a div, and put it to the background.. But the divs (layers) on top is nok effected by the  opacity:0.6 and filter:alpha(opacity=60) ??

Comment: What is it you are trying to watermark...the image or something else.

Answer (score 12):

HTML

```
<div class="watermark">
    <div class="col-md-12">Something else</div>
    <div class="col-md-12">Something more..</div>
    <div class="col-md-12">Something at the end</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
  .watermark {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.watermark::after {
  content: "";
 background:url(https://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo11w.png);
  opacity: 0.2;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;   
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/yg0xgm9t/1/)

Comment: I have a angular ng-repeat to show different background images. How do I get this attach, with your solution?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yg0xgm9t/4/ check this demo, only you need to change background-image url inline.

Comment: Could I get the cornes of the backgroud images rounded? class="img-rounded" dont work..

Answer (score -1):

Try this [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/stanze/yg0xgm9t/2/)

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="watermark"></div>
    <div class="inner-container">
        <div class="col-md-12">Something else</div>
        <div class="col-md-12">Something more..</div>
        <div class="col-md-12">Something at the end</div>
    </div>
</div>
```