# Making Text Watermark on Image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, watermark

I am trying to add watermark as text to my image. I have been following this link http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Add-Image-Or-Text-Watermarks-To-Images-with-jQuery-watermark.html as a tutorial. Any idea's of what I am doing wrong or other suggestions
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ak5si.png

Comment: Here's a pure css solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30234986/watermark-background-images-in-div

Comment: Oh, I see the problem here.  You haven't written any code.  Fix that and try again.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest using a image program such as Photoshop to add the watermark. Make a copy of the image and edit the text within the Photoshop file. Gimp is a free alternative to Photoshop and can get the job done just as well.

Having the Photofile file will allow you to have more control on where the watermark shows up and how clear it is to see.

Comment: partially true, there are scenarios you'd want generated watermark. e.g. You want to watermark something that a user set for you `"Belong to MyUsername"`, or watermark with different texts for different reasons...