# How to displaye watermark background image in every section on onepage site

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am currently trying html, css and bootstrap and have the following problem

I try to make a logo on a website as a background. How to this i have already found out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30234986/watermark-background-images-in-div).

The website consists of only one HTML file. Here I have defined several sections. You can jump to certain sections using menu navigation.

```
<div class="container-fluid p-0 ">
  <section class="resume-section p-3 p-lg-5 d-flex align-items-center" id="a">
  </section>

  <section class="resume-section p-3 p-lg-5 d-flex align-items-center" id="b">
  </section>

  <section class="resume-section p-3 p-lg-5 d-flex align-items-center" id="c">
  </section>

  <section class="resume-section p-3 p-lg-5 d-flex align-items-center" id="d">
  </section>
</div>
```

What I want now is that the watermark always appears in the middle, even if I scroll the website down or up. if i use the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30234986/watermark-background-images-in-div). The watermark appears only on the first section

how can achieve that  the watermark always appears in the middle, even if I scroll?

Comment: Have you tried any CSS so that I can give further help?

Comment: yes, i have used the css from the solution  that i linked in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the CSS property `position: fixed` as so:

```
.watermark:after{
    position: fixed;
}
```